# Scriptella data copy error on mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, etl, scriptella

I am using [Scriptella](https://scriptella.org/) to copy data from one table  to another table(different database) on Mysql. For source, I have used table [film](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables-film.html) from Mysql sample database Sakila.

While copying the data I am getting this error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" scriptella.execution.EtlExecutorException: Location: /etl/query[1]/script[1]
JDBC provider exception: Unable to get parameter 4
Error codes: [S1009, 0]
Driver exception: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '2006' from column 4 to TIMESTAMP.
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.execute(EtlExecutor.java:190)
    at com.zensar.scrptellaTest.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: scriptella.core.ExceptionInterceptor$ExecutionException: /etl/query[1]/script[1] failed: Unable to get parameter 4
    at scriptella.core.ExceptionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionInterceptor.java:44)
    at scriptella.core.QueryExecutor$QueryCtxDecorator.processRow(QueryExecutor.java:114)
    at scriptella.jdbc.StatementWrapper.query(StatementWrapper.java:92)
    at scriptella.jdbc.SqlExecutor.statementParsed(SqlExecutor.java:128)
    at scriptella.jdbc.SqlParserBase.handleStatement(SqlParserBase.java:129)
    at scriptella.jdbc.SqlParserBase.parse(SqlParserBase.java:72)
    at scriptella.jdbc.SqlExecutor.execute(SqlExecutor.java:85)
    at scriptella.jdbc.JdbcConnection.executeQuery(JdbcConnection.java:222)
    at scriptella.core.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:71)
    at scriptella.core.ContentExecutor.execute(ContentExecutor.java:73)
    at scriptella.core.ElementInterceptor.executeNext(ElementInterceptor.java:56)
    at scriptella.core.StatisticInterceptor.execute(StatisticInterceptor.java:41)
    at scriptella.core.ElementInterceptor.executeNext(ElementInterceptor.java:56)
    at scriptella.core.ConnectionInterceptor.execute(ConnectionInterceptor.java:36)
    at scriptella.core.ElementInterceptor.executeNext(ElementInterceptor.java:56)
    at scriptella.core.ExceptionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionInterceptor.java:39)
    at scriptella.core.Session.execute(Session.java:103)
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.execute(EtlExecutor.java:227)
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.execute(EtlExecutor.java:183)
    ... 1 more
```

This is one row from the table.

```
'1', 'ACADEMY DINOSAUR', 'A Epic Drama of a Feminist And a Mad Scientist who must Battle a Teacher in The Canadian Rockies', 2006, '1', NULL, '6', '0.99', '86', '20.99', 'PG', 'Deleted Scenes,Behind the Scenes', '2006-02-15 05:03:42'
```

Here it the DDL statement of both the tables.

**sakila.film**

```
CREATE TABLE `film` (
  `film_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `release_year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `original_language_id` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rental_duration` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  `rental_rate` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4.99',
  `length` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `replacement_cost` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '19.99',
  `rating` enum('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17') DEFAULT 'G',
  `special_features` set('Trailers','Commentaries','Deleted Scenes','Behind the Scenes') DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`),
  KEY `idx_title` (`title`),
  KEY `idx_fk_language_id` (`language_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_original_language_id` (`original_language_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_film_language` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`language_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_film_language_original` FOREIGN KEY (`original_language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`language_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**trg.film**

```
CREATE TABLE `film` (
  `film_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `release_year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `original_language_id` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rental_duration` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  `rental_rate` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4.99',
  `length` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `replacement_cost` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '19.99',
  `rating` enum('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17') DEFAULT 'G',
  `special_features` set('Trailers','Commentaries','Deleted Scenes','Behind the Scenes') DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Scriptella etl.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <description>Scriptella ETL File Template.</description>
    <!-- Connection declarations -->
    <connection id="source" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sakila" user="root" password="12345" />
    <connection id="target" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/trg" user="root" password="12345" />

    <!-- Uncomment and modify to run a query-based transformation -->
    <query connection-id="source">
        SELECT * FROM film;
        <script connection-id="target">
            INSERT INTO film VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7, ?8, ?9, ?10, ?11, ?12, ?13);
        </script>
    </query>

</etl>
```

**Java Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws EtlExecutorException {
        ProgressIndicatorBase indicatorBase = new ProgressIndicatorBase() {

            @Override
            protected void show(String label, double progress) {
                System.out.println(label + "--> " + progress);

            }
        };

          EtlExecutor.newExecutor(new File("etl.xml")).execute(indicatorBase);
    }
```

Please tell me where I am doing wrong or is there any workaround to solve it.

Comment: It is okay if someone down-vote a question, but adding a comment would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you receive is

```
Driver exception: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '2006' from column 4 to TIMESTAMP.
```

It seems that the particular DB line contains value 2006 in a column where a TIMESTAMP type is expected, the format of which for MySQL seems to be

```
TIMESTAMP - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But why it is converting 2006 to timestamp as  column `release_year` is of `year` type.

Comment: @g_p: I have no MySQL available so I cannot reproduce it for you. I would suggest to put breakpoints at the relevant parts of your stacktrace and try to debug why this type conversion is being attempted. scriptella.core.QueryExecutor$QueryCtxDecorator.processRow(QueryExecutor.java:114) seems to be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I know.
Just put quotes around the parameter

?4  should look like "?4"

At the source the date is being casted as a string.
So when the insert is created with the string date without the quotes, the date parsing stops after year leaving you with just a number